# Adding a column to all rows of a large Postgres database

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a PostgreSQL database where I need to update a specific column based on some calculations performed in Python. This is running very slow and seems to slow down the longer the code runs (it got through about 3% of the rows in 12 hours).

I don't think I'm resource constrained based on Windows task manager. I have have RAM and CPU available. Disk active is 100%, but is performing below NVME read/write speeds.

The database has about 1.6 billion rows. `id` is the primary key. I'm interacting with it using psycopg2 as follows:

```
import psycopg2


def retrieve_raw_content_batch(batch_size):
    with db_connect() as conn:
        with conn.cursor('testit') as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT id, columnoftext FROM table;")
            while True:
                rows = cursor.fetchmany(batch_size)
                if not rows:
                    break

                yield rows


def update_database(upload_list):
    with db_connect() as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            update_query = "UPDATE table SET col1 = %s, col2 = %s WHERE id = %s"
            psycopg2.extras.execute_batch(cursor, update_query, upload_list)


def do_stuff(row_batch): 
    for rows in row_batch:
        upload_list = []
        for row in rows:
            #calculate to get id, col1, col2
            upload_list.append((id, col1, col2))
        update_database(upload_list)


def main(batch_size):
    rows_batch = retrieve_raw_content_batch(batch_size)
    do_stuff(rows_batch)
```

I tried to modify the postgresql.conf file by increasing `max_wal_size` to 10GB, but I am relatively new to Postgres. I'm not sure how to optimize my database configuration or if this is even the issue.

I am also wondering whether it makes more sense to create a new table with `COPY` and use `JOIN` after, instead of `UPDATE` each row individually.

Comment: `COPY` to staging table and then `UPDATE` from staging table to final table.

Comment: What kind of calculation you do on Python? Depending on those processes it might change. Which partion of work took 12 hours? Only fetching, fetching and processing or fetching is done and processing was taking 12 hours?

Comment: I am doing sentiment analysis on tweets stored in the db (each row is a tweet). When I ran the profiler, the majority of time was on the inserts (90%), the fetching and processing were quite fast. Also when I tried out the suggestion below, the UPDATE was the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is taking so long is that you are using an UPDATE for every single row, meaning you have 1.6 billion transactions - this is gonna take forever.

If you split the UPDATEs into batches, you could greatly reduce the number of transactions. The safest and most efficient way in postgres would be to make a temporary table that batch UPDATEs and transfers. The solution is relatively simple as long as this works for your usecase:

```
def update_database_in_batches(upload_list, batch_size):
    with db_connect() as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            for i in range(0, len(upload_list), batch_size):
                temp_table_query = """
                CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table (id INTEGER, col1 INTEGER, col2 INTEGER)
                ON COMMIT DROP;
                """
                cursor.execute(temp_table_query)

                # Batch insert to the temp_table
                insert_query = "INSERT INTO temp_table (id, col1, col2) VALUES %s"
                psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cursor, insert_query, upload_list[i:i+batch_size])

                # Update the main table from the temporary table
                update_query = """
                UPDATE table
                SET col1 = temp_table.col1, col2 = temp_table.col2
                FROM temp_table
                WHERE table.id = temp_table.id;
                """
                cursor.execute(update_query)
```

You're gonna have to specify `batch_size`, etc and maybe small modifications, but this is the general structure

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Isn't this what `execute_batch` does in the background, though?

Comment: It isn't no. The function I sent uses a single command instead of multilple - execute_batch executes each command in a separate transaction

Comment: I'll try it out, thanks. Is it generally true that using UPDATE with a TABLE already in Postgres will be faster than UPDATE from Python? 

I'm also going to try replace `INSERT` with `COPY`, which I think is supposed to be faster.

Comment: Completely depends on your process of updating, but for this example and the method we used, yes. Sure, best of luck!

Comment: The final `UPDATE` is still quite slow - I've made batch sizes of 100k and it's processing 100 batches/hour, with almost all of the time spent on `UPDATE`. I still have resources available, so it seems like it should be possible to make it faster.

Comment: This offers no advantage over `execute_batch()` and runs two transaction bound queries the `INSERT` then the `UPDATE` in series. Don't see how this is going to help speed things up.